# Why is Retrofit omitting certain characters from my URL request?

Tags: java, android, http, web, retrofit

**Update:** The issue is **NOT** to do with needing to encode the URL. This is done by Retrofit. If I encode the URL, and then pass it to Retrofit, the URL gets encoded twice and ends up looking like this:

[https://example.com/api/get_user_info/?id=12345&cookie=user@email.com%257C1492357107%257CfyVzRUYC9h%257C4f889e1976c2cd87aac](https://s)

Note the `%257C`. First round is `| -> %7C`. Second round is `%7C -> %257C`

I am trying to execute an HTTP GET request using Retrofit. The request looks like this:
[https://example.com/api/get_user_info/?id=12345&cookie=user@email.com|1492357107|fyVzRUYC9h|4f889e1976c2cd87aac](https://s)

In code, the call looks like this

```
@GET("get_user_info")
Call<ResponseBody> getUserMeta(
            @Query("id") int userId,
            @Query("cookie") String cookie
);
```

When I execute this query, the `Request` looks like this:

```
Request{method=GET, url=https://example.com/api/get_user_info/?id=12345&cookie=user@email.com|1492357107|fyVzRUYC9h|4f889e1976c2cd87aac, tag=null}
```

(Taken from the console after logging `call.request().toString()`)

After the call is executed, I receive an error from my API saying that the cookie is invalid. The Response looks like this:

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://example.com/api/get_user_info/?id=12345&cookie=user@email.com1492357107fyVzRUYC9h4f889e1976c2cd87aac}
```

(Taken from the console after loggin `Response<ResponseBody> response.toString()`)

As you can see, the two URLs are not the same. The `|` character has somehow been removed from the cookie parameter in the response's URL.

You might think that this has something to do with my API, and that the cookie is in fact incorrect, but if I copy and paste the `Request` URL directly into my browser, it executes with no error (status 200). If Retrofit executes the call, I get 404.

Evidently, Retrofit is executing the second, incorrect URL. This is clearly the case because the first URL does not return a 404 when executed in the browser, but the second one does.

What is going on? Any help would be much appreciated.

Additional info:

I am using `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'` in my app module's build.gradle.

I am instantiating my Retrofit client like so:

```
Retrofit retroFit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/")
                    .build();
```

Comment: URL Encode the pipe with `%7C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [`encoding`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/90729eb2ae2f3329281c1f9813ab1de3daa71ad0/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit2/RequestBuilderTest.java#L1488-L1498) on your cookies :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("get_user_info")
Call<ResponseBody> getUserMeta(
    @Query("id") int userId,
    @Query(value ="cookie", encode = true) String cookie

    );
```

Comment: Retrofit raises an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST).`

Comment: @Vasilisfoo it will be a great idea if you have asked new question with some code.

Comment: @Ibrahim it would be dublicate , I have the exact same problem , pipe character is being removed from cookie. I have tried what you suggest but with no luck .

Comment: @Vasilisfoo it's seems not the same issue, you are doing some thing illegal, maybe you not specifing the `@FormUrlEncoded` on on the retrofit method only.